# Installing a Brother MFC-240C on 12.10

Tags: printing, brother

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10, 64-bit, with encryption, on my laptop.  I've got an old Brother MFC-240C that's connected via a USB port.  I was able to locate the appropriate drivers on the Brother web site:

- `mfc240clpr-1.0.1-1.i386.rpm` and
- `mfc240ccupswrapper-1.0.1-1.i386.rpm`

and install them.  My laptop sees the printer, and detects when I unplug it or turn it off, but when I try to send print jobs to it, it doesn't respond. The printer worked fine when I had Windows installed on my laptop, so I know it's not that.

Has anyone run into this problem?  Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using USB or network printing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose your printer from the 'Model' tab in the printer options (System settings/printers). Just click over whatever occupies the space to the right the word 'model', and click on 'select from database'. It'll be under Brother, prolly something like 'MFC-240clpr(cups)'.

By the way, don't worry about the .rpm file, it's usable only for Linux distros using RedHat. Just use both the LPR & cupswrapper .deb's version from here...

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-240C